# Start/stop mediaplayer (eg. Spotify) from dotnet?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

On my Microsoft keyboard I have a media player play/pause button.

This button pauses both Spotify, Mediaplay etc. so it's like it broadcasts a play/pause command.

Pressing this button gives me KeyCode = MediaPlayPause in .net.

How can I send this command from .net?

I need to pause/play Spotify from my .net app.

I've tried this...

```
Keyboard.SendKey(Keys.MediaPlayPause)

...

Public Class Keyboard
    Declare Sub keybd_event Lib "user32.dll" (ByVal bVk As Byte, ByVal bScan As Byte, ByVal dwFlags As Int32, ByVal dwExtraInfo As Int32)

    Public Shared Sub SendKey(ByVal key As Keys)
        keybd_event(CByte(key), 0, 0, 0)
    End Sub
End Class
```

No luck.

Comment: Updated my post - I've already tried that. No luck.

Comment: Spotify has an API that will help you: https://developer.spotify.com/docs/apps/api/1.0/api-models-player.html

Comment: Use SendInput instead http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646304(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been already answered here
[VB Simulate a key press](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17842612/vb-simulate-a-key-press)

Anyway the full guide is here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/172wfck9.aspx