# Receive OS level key-press events in C# application

Tags: c#, keyboard-shortcuts, media-player, keyboard-hook

i dont know a better title for the question , but i`ll illustrate my problem.

I am working on application that acts like a mp3 player , it uses the Multimedia keys to play/pause , stop the song , i actually made it work but the FormApplication must be in the top [Focused]

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message msg)
{
    if (msg.Msg == 0x319)   // WM_APPCOMMAND message
    {
        // extract cmd from LPARAM (as GET_APPCOMMAND_LPARAM macro does)
        int cmd = (int)((uint)msg.LParam >> 16 & ~0xf000);
        switch (cmd)
        {
            case 13:  // APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_STOP constant
                MessageBox.Show("Stop");
                break;
            case 14:  // APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE
                MessageBox.Show("Play/Pause");
                break;
            case 11:  // APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_NEXTTRACK
                MessageBox.Show("Next");
                break;
            case 12:  // APPCOMMAND_MEDIA_PREVIOUSTRACK
                MessageBox.Show("Previous");
                break;
            default:  
                break;
        }
    }
    base.WndProc(ref msg);
}


private void Form1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    Message m = new Message();
    m.Msg = e.KeyChar;

    WndProc(ref m);
}
```

So what i need to do is : making the multimedia keys work even if the program is on the background and is not on top or focused , just like how winamp and Windows Media Player works.

I searched a lot on the internet but most of them gives me a way similar to the one i am using.

Thank you a lot for your help in advance.

Comment: So, even from what you wrote, it seems like the problem isn't in the part of code you put here, but in the keyboard hook itself. How are you catching the global keyboard hook ? It seems like you just have a local application hook, and not a global one...

Comment: Here's an article i once read to implement this, and managed to get it right... http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture Media Keys when Application is Minimized](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196883/capture-media-keys-when-application-is-minimized)

Answer (score 2):

You need a OS level keyboard hook. e.g `user32.dll` `SetWindowsHookEx` via `P/Invoke`. You can find below a sample, but you'll have to tailor it to your needs.

Note: The `Dispatcher` here is the WPF dispatcher so that `RawKeyEventArgs` can be raised.

`KeyboardListener.cs`

```
/// <summary>
    /// Listens keyboard globally.
    /// 
    /// <remarks>Uses WH_KEYBOARD_LL.</remarks>
    /// </summary>
    public class KeyboardListener : IDisposable
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Creates global keyboard listener.
        /// </summary>
        public KeyboardListener(Dispatcher dispatcher)
        {
            // Dispatcher thread handling the KeyDown/KeyUp events.
            _dispatcher = dispatcher;

            // We have to store the LowLevelKeyboardProc, so that it is not garbage collected runtime
            _hookedLowLevelKeyboardProc = LowLevelKeyboardProc;

            // Set the hook
            _hookId = InterceptKeys.SetHook(_hookedLowLevelKeyboardProc);

            // Assign the asynchronous callback event
            _hookedKeyboardCallbackAsync = new KeyboardCallbackAsync(KeyboardListener_KeyboardCallbackAsync);
        }

        private readonly Dispatcher _dispatcher;

        /// <summary>
        /// Destroys global keyboard listener.
        /// </summary>
        ~KeyboardListener()
        {
            Dispose();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when any of the keys is pressed down.
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler<RawKeyEventArgs> KeyDown;

        /// <summary>
        /// Fired when any of the keys is released.
        /// </summary>
        public event EventHandler<RawKeyEventArgs> KeyUp;

        #region Inner workings

        /// <summary>
        /// Hook ID
        /// </summary>
        private readonly IntPtr _hookId = IntPtr.Zero;

        /// <summary>
        /// Asynchronous callback hook.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="character">Character</param>
        /// <param name="keyEvent">Keyboard event</param>
        /// <param name="vkCode">VKCode</param>
        private delegate void KeyboardCallbackAsync(InterceptKeys.KeyEvent keyEvent, int vkCode, string character);

        /// <summary>
        /// Actual callback hook.
        /// 
        /// <remarks>Calls asynchronously the asyncCallback.</remarks>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="nCode"></param>
        /// <param name="wParam"></param>
        /// <param name="lParam"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.NoInlining)]
        private IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0)
                if (wParam.ToUInt32() == (int)InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_KEYDOWN ||
                    wParam.ToUInt32() == (int)InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_KEYUP ||
                    wParam.ToUInt32() == (int)InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_SYSKEYDOWN ||
                    wParam.ToUInt32() == (int)InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_SYSKEYUP)
                {
                    // Captures the character(s) pressed only on WM_KEYDOWN
                    string chars = InterceptKeys.VKCodeToString((uint)Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam),
                                                                (wParam.ToUInt32() == (int)InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_KEYDOWN ||
                                                                 wParam.ToUInt32() == (int)InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_SYSKEYDOWN));

                    _hookedKeyboardCallbackAsync.BeginInvoke((InterceptKeys.KeyEvent)wParam.ToUInt32(), Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam), chars, null, null);
                }

            return InterceptKeys.CallNextHookEx(_hookId, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Event to be invoked asynchronously (BeginInvoke) each time key is pressed.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly KeyboardCallbackAsync _hookedKeyboardCallbackAsync;

        /// <summary>
        /// Contains the hooked callback in runtime.
        /// </summary>
        private readonly InterceptKeys.LowLevelKeyboardProc _hookedLowLevelKeyboardProc;

        /// <summary>
        /// HookCallbackAsync procedure that calls accordingly the KeyDown or KeyUp events.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="keyEvent">Keyboard event</param>
        /// <param name="vkCode">VKCode</param>
        /// <param name="character">Character as string.</param>
        void KeyboardListener_KeyboardCallbackAsync(InterceptKeys.KeyEvent keyEvent, int vkCode, string character)
        {
            switch (keyEvent)
            {
                // KeyDown events
                case InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_KEYDOWN:
                    if (KeyDown != null)
                        _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<RawKeyEventArgs>(KeyDown), this, new RawKeyEventArgs(vkCode, false, character));
                    break;
                case InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
                    if (KeyDown != null)
                        _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<RawKeyEventArgs>(KeyDown), this, new RawKeyEventArgs(vkCode, true, character));
                    break;

                // KeyUp events
                case InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_KEYUP:
                    if (KeyUp != null)
                        _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<RawKeyEventArgs>(KeyUp), this, new RawKeyEventArgs(vkCode, false, character));
                    break;
                case InterceptKeys.KeyEvent.WM_SYSKEYUP:
                    if (KeyUp != null)
                        _dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new EventHandler<RawKeyEventArgs>(KeyUp), this, new RawKeyEventArgs(vkCode, true, character));
                    break;

                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region IDisposable Members

        /// <summary>
        /// Disposes the hook.
        /// <remarks>This call is required as it calls the UnhookWindowsHookEx.</remarks>
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            InterceptKeys.UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookId);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

`InterceptKeys.cs`

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Winapi Key interception helper class.
    /// </summary>
    internal static class InterceptKeys
    {
        public delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(int nCode, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;

        /// <summary>
        /// Key event
        /// </summary>
        public enum KeyEvent : int
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Key down
            /// </summary>
            WM_KEYDOWN = 256,

            /// <summary>
            /// Key up
            /// </summary>
            WM_KEYUP = 257,

            /// <summary>
            /// System key up
            /// </summary>
            WM_SYSKEYUP = 261,

            /// <summary>
            /// System key down
            /// </summary>
            WM_SYSKEYDOWN = 260
        }

        public static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        internal static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, UIntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

        #region Convert VKCode to string
        // Note: Sometimes single VKCode represents multiple chars, thus string. 
        // E.g. typing "^1" (notice that when pressing 1 the both characters appear, 
        // because of this behavior, "^" is called dead key)

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern int ToUnicodeEx(uint wVirtKey, uint wScanCode, byte[] lpKeyState, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] System.Text.StringBuilder pwszBuff, int cchBuff, uint wFlags, IntPtr dwhkl);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool GetKeyboardState(byte[] lpKeyState);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern uint MapVirtualKeyEx(uint uCode, uint uMapType, IntPtr dwhkl);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetKeyboardLayout(uint dwLayout);

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint lpdwProcessId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        private static extern bool AttachThreadInput(uint idAttach, uint idAttachTo, bool fAttach);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        private static extern uint GetCurrentThreadId();

        private static uint _lastVKCode = 0;
        private static uint _lastScanCode = 0;
        private static byte[] _lastKeyState = new byte[255];
        private static bool _lastIsDead = false;

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert VKCode to Unicode.
        /// <remarks>isKeyDown is required for because of keyboard state inconsistencies!</remarks>
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="vkCode">VKCode</param>
        /// <param name="isKeyDown">Is the key down event?</param>
        /// <returns>String representing single unicode character.</returns>
        public static string VKCodeToString(uint vkCode, bool isKeyDown)
        {
            // ToUnicodeEx needs StringBuilder, it populates that during execution.
            var sbString = new System.Text.StringBuilder(5);

            var bKeyState = new byte[255];
            bool bKeyStateStatus;
            bool isDead = false;

            // Gets the current windows window handle, threadID, processID
            IntPtr currentHWnd = GetForegroundWindow();
            uint currentProcessID;
            uint currentWindowThreadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(currentHWnd, out currentProcessID);

            // This programs Thread ID
            uint thisProgramThreadId = GetCurrentThreadId();

            // Attach to active thread so we can get that keyboard state
            if (AttachThreadInput(thisProgramThreadId, currentWindowThreadID, true))
            {
                // Current state of the modifiers in keyboard
                bKeyStateStatus = GetKeyboardState(bKeyState);

                // Detach
                AttachThreadInput(thisProgramThreadId, currentWindowThreadID, false);
            }
            else
            {
                // Could not attach, perhaps it is this process?
                bKeyStateStatus = GetKeyboardState(bKeyState);
            }

            // On failure we return empty string.
            if (!bKeyStateStatus)
                return "";

            // Gets the layout of keyboard
            IntPtr hkl = GetKeyboardLayout(currentWindowThreadID);

            // Maps the virtual keycode
            uint lScanCode = MapVirtualKeyEx(vkCode, 0, hkl);

            // Keyboard state goes inconsistent if this is not in place. In other words, we need to call above commands in UP events also.
            if (!isKeyDown)
                return "";

            // Converts the VKCode to unicode
            int relevantKeyCountInBuffer = ToUnicodeEx(vkCode, lScanCode, bKeyState, sbString, sbString.Capacity, (uint)0, hkl);

            string ret = "";

            switch (relevantKeyCountInBuffer)
            {
                    // Dead keys (^,`...)
                case -1:
                    isDead = true;

                    // We must clear the buffer because ToUnicodeEx messed it up, see below.
                    ClearKeyboardBuffer(vkCode, lScanCode, hkl);
                    break;

                case 0:
                    break;

                    // Single character in buffer
                case 1:
                    ret = sbString[0].ToString();
                    break;

                    // Two or more (only two of them is relevant)
                case 2:
                default:
                    ret = sbString.ToString().Substring(0, 2);
                    break;
            }

            // We inject the last dead key back, since ToUnicodeEx removed it.
            // More about this peculiar behavior see e.g: 
            //   http://www.experts-exchange.com/Programming/System/Windows__Programming/Q_23453780.html
            //   http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/archive/2005/01/19/355870.aspx
            //   http://blogs.msdn.com/michkap/archive/2007/10/27/5717859.aspx
            if (_lastVKCode != 0 && _lastIsDead)
            {
                var sbTemp = new System.Text.StringBuilder(5);
                ToUnicodeEx(_lastVKCode, _lastScanCode, _lastKeyState, sbTemp, sbTemp.Capacity, (uint)0, hkl);
                _lastVKCode = 0;

                return ret;
            }

            // Save these
            _lastScanCode = lScanCode;
            _lastVKCode = vkCode;
            _lastIsDead = isDead;
            _lastKeyState = (byte[])bKeyState.Clone();

            return ret;
        }

        private static void ClearKeyboardBuffer(uint vk, uint sc, IntPtr hkl)
        {
            var sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder(10);

            int rc;
            do
            {
                var lpKeyStateNull = new Byte[255];
                rc = ToUnicodeEx(vk, sc, lpKeyStateNull, sb, sb.Capacity, 0, hkl);
            } while (rc < 0);
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

`RawKeyEventArgs.cs`

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Raw KeyEvent arguments.
    /// </summary>
    public class RawKeyEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public bool IsSysKey { get; private set; }

        public Key Key { get; private set; }

        public int VKCode { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Convert to string.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Returns string representation of this key, if not possible empty string is returned.</returns>
        public override string ToString()
        {
            if (Character == null)
                return string.Empty;

            return Character;
        }

        public string Character { get; private set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Create raw keyevent arguments.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="vkCode"></param>
        /// <param name="isSysKey"></param>
        /// <param name="character">Character</param>
        public RawKeyEventArgs(int vkCode, bool isSysKey, string character)
        {
            VKCode = vkCode;
            IsSysKey = isSysKey;
            Character = character;
            Key = KeyInterop.KeyFromVirtualKey(vkCode);
        }

    }
```