# Detect pressed key on Desktop

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to know how can i detect which key pressed (for example on Desktop or my computer ).
when detect pressed key show it with `MessageBox`

how can i do this?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1100285/how-to-detect-the-currently-pressed-key ?

Comment: @Ankush: No, that one is about detecting keys pressed in *your* app.  I'm sure there *is* a duplicate of global keyboard hooks on SO though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# : Keyboard Hook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391025/c-sharp-keyboard-hook)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detecting the key presses outside of your application requires installing a [Low Level Keyboard Hook](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  Here is a [CodeProject article demonstrating the process](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19004/A-Simple-C-Global-Low-Level-Keyboard-Hook).