# Using keybd_event in user32.ddl to know of a key is pressed. In C#

Tags: c#, .net

I am currently working on a program, where I need to get Event's if a Key is pressed. (Even if my program is not focused / minimized.)
For that I want to use the keybd_event.
I also found some things in the internet, but nothing helpfull for me. (I also looked in the MSDN, but I didn't find it something helpfull.)

What do I need implement to get this working?

Thank you for your answers

Marcel

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# : Keyboard Hook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391025/c-sharp-keyboard-hook)

Answer (score 0):

The `keybd_event` documentation states that the function should be used for *generating* keystrokes and *not* for detecting them:

> Synthesizes a keystroke. The system can use such a synthesized keystroke to generate a WM_KEYUP or WM_KEYDOWN message.

The documentation also states that the  method is deprecated (which could explain the lack of resources):

> Note  This function has been superseded. Use SendInput instead.

... It looks as though you need a different function.

To detect a keypress irrespective of whether the window is in focus or not, you have a few options:

- Use the `RegisterHotkey` function to detect the pressing of a hotkey.
- Use the `SetWindowsHookEx` function to *hook* the keyboard and to receive notifications whenever *any* key is pressed.
- Use the `GetKeyState` function to poll the state of a key.

Each of these functions have a copious number of tutorials that are only  a Google search away.