# Detect windows key pressed with hotekey

Tags: c#, winforms

How can I detect `LWin` and `RWin` keys with hot key?

Right now I'm using the example code given [here](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/) but it only detect the win key if its used as a modifier. I want to know how to detect the win key. Something like this:

`private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.LWin || e.KeyCode == Keys.RWin)
        WriteLine("Windows key pressed");
}`

But with the ability of detecting it if the form is not focused.

Comment: Maybe a duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391025/c-sharp-keyboard-hook

Comment: You need an Hook if you want the ability of decteing it evenf if the form is not focused. I developped one, this link helped me a lot : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/toub/archive/2006/05/03/589423.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my answer in this question: [C# : Keyboard Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391025/c-sharp-keyboard-hook)

> [Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)
>
> I found that article quite useful.

Note: that credits goes to Kendall Frey for answering that SO question.