# c# send a keypress to the form only

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

So I have a form with a webbrowser in it. It needs to put some text into a text field input and then it has to press enter to send the text. But the problem I got is when I am doing something else it tries to press enter in that program I am currently using.

```
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("chatMessage").SetAttribute("Test");
webBrowser1.Select();
webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("chatMessage").Focus();
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait("{ENTER}");
```

Any idea on what I should use instead?

Here is the html code.

```
<form id="chatForm">
   <div style="margin:5px">        
        <div class="form-group" style="margin-bottom:5px">
           <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Type here to chat..." id="chatMessage" maxlength="200" autocomplete="off">
        </div>                          

        <div class="pull-left">
           <strong>Users Online: <span id="isonline">0</span></strong>
        </div>

        <div class="checkbox pull-right" style="margin:0px">
           <label class="noselect">
           <input type="checkbox" id="scroll">
           <strong>Pause chat</strong>
           </label>
        </div>

        <br>

        <div class="pull-left">
           <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#chatRules">Chat Rules</a>
        </div>

    </div>

</form>
```

Comment: There are UI automation classes designed for doing this. But I don't think it's necessary in this case. You should be able to just send the data directly. One wonders why your application is submitting and sending a chat message inside of a web browser in the first place. This seems like a strange design.

Comment: Creating a bot, that I need to be able to type to and get some info back from in the chat.

Comment: Can you explain more in depth on how I should do it or give me a link with more info.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible. All I could think of is focusing your application for a split second, send the keys and jump back to where you were. But this holds so many errors and will disturb you at least for a little moment that you won't be satisfied with it. Is there no chance for you to send the data/message on a direct way instead of simulating the keyboard input?

Comment: You can see the html code above, and as I said I have tried to submit it.

Answer (score -2):

Checkout the key hook

[C# : Keyboard Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391025/c-sharp-keyboard-hook)

Comment: I don't need to check if the user presses a button, I need the program to click enter but only for the program. If I am doing something else and my program tries to click enter then it clicks enter in the wrong program I have open and not in the program that it should press enter in.