# global keyboard hook/Raw input Capture keyboard input

Tags: c#, keyboard-hook, raw-input

Does any of you know how to capture data from a keyboard based on the VID or PID for the keyboard?

well it's possible with raw input in C# but then i can't block the data, or well redirect it to my application.. and well i can block the data with a global keyboard hook but then i can't see what source it's comming from.. so is it possible to merge these two? or well is there anykind of plugin of some sort i can use? would be great if it was in .net!

I've been searching and trying to find something for days.. but no luck yet!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7196883/capture-media-keys-when-application-is-minimized

Comment: yeah well.. that's just how to capture the keys isen't it? the problem is that i want to block the data.. so it wont hit any other application.. from a specific device!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this program to do the job: http://nate.dynalias.net/dev/keyboardredirector.rails