# Stop music/audio that is played by other app from a dot net core winform app?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, bluetooth

A remote bluetooth headset is playing audio from computer. E.g., browser, spotify audio to a bluetooth headset. We want to stop/ pause music/audio from our app. How can we do it?

Searched for methods but did not find solution.

Comment: See [Send MediaPlayPause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199203/send-key-mediaplaypause-to-an-application-without-setting-focus-to-it).

Answer (score 2):

#### UWP

UWP apps are running in sandbox which are isolated from system, UWP cannot access other app's process and is restricted when accessing system resources.
So, you **can't stop/pause music/audio played by system or other Apps**.

---

#### WinForm

You can use Win32 API [keybd_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event) with `VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE` to simulate pause key input.

Comment: Hi, How to detect if music is playing? Since play pause will start playing if it was paused? We need only pause state actually.

Comment: WinForm, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45422255/determine-if-windows-is-currently-playing-sound). It use [IAudioMeterInformation::GetPeakValue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/endpointvolume/nf-endpointvolume-iaudiometerinformation-getpeakvalue) to detect if music is playing.