# How To Pause All The Sounds Of The System When The Call Is Connected

Tags: c#, .net, audio, uwp, naudio

I want to create an UWP app which should pause the all the sound of my Windows system when there is call is connected in the Google meet, Zoom etc.

How to do this by using C#.

Comment: Have you checked my new reply about can this be achieved by using WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just from UWP side, UWP apps are running in sandbox which are isolated from system, it cannot access other app's process and is restricted when accessing system resources. So, you can't pause Windows system sound from UWP.

But there is a solution, you can use Desktop-bridge to start a desktop application, call Win32 API [keybd_event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-keybd_event) with `VK_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUS` to simulate pause key input. You can refer to Stefan Wick's blog [UWP with Desktop Extension – Part 2](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-2/)

Comment: Can I achieve it by using WPF?

Comment: In WPF, you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7199203/send-key-mediaplaypause-to-an-application-without-setting-focus-to-it?answertab=modifieddesc#tab-top), use the Win32 API `keybd_event` directly, no need for Desktop-bridge.